# Rails paperclip is there any way to resize images without using imagemagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3

I have been using the paperclip gem at https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip. Is there any way of resizing images using paperclip alone, without having to use Imagemagick? If not, are there any other gems/plugins that do not require ImageMagick to resize images on upload?

Thanks All, any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use  fastimage_resize.
it is light, but less powerfull